# How do I add JS libraries in DrupalGap

Tags: javascript

I am hoping to add Slick Library within my DrupalGap but when I try to use it, I am unable to.

The library is added normally within index.html but when one my node page (which has the HTML in it) tries to use it, it doesn't work.

Any idea how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the Slick carousel `.js` file in the `index.html` file is correct.

You can use the brand the new `hook_entity_view_alter` to attach a `pageshow` handler to the node's page:

- http://api.drupalgap.org/7/global.html#hook_entity_view_alter
- http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Pages/Page_Events

In the `pageshow` handler is when you'd initialize the carousel. The `pageshow` event fires after page is shown to the user. There are a few other hooks you could use to have a chance to place the `pageshow` event on a node's page within the app:

- http://api.drupalgap.org/7/global.html#hook_entity_post_render_content
- http://api.drupalgap.org/7/global.html#hook_entity_post_render_field

The `hook_entity_view_alter` is the most powerful and is brand new, so you need the latest `bin/drupalgap.min.js` file and the latest `jdrupal.min.js` file to run it. But that is the hook I'd recommend using